# Let $X,Y,Z$ be nonempty sets. Then $|(X^Y)^Z|=|X^{Y\times Z}|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, cardinals

> Let $X,Y,Z$ be nonempty sets. Then $\left |\left(X^Y\right)^Z\right|=\left|X^{Y\times Z}\right|$.

---

Please help me verify this proof! Thank you so much!

---

**My attempt:**

We define a mapping $F$ that assigns each $f\in \left(X^Y\right)^Z$ to each $g\in X^{Y\times Z}$ by $$\forall (y,z)\in Y\times Z:g(y,z):=f(z)(y)$$

1. $F$ is surjective

For $g\in X^{Y\times Z}$, we define $f$ by $f(z)(y):=g(y,z)$ for all $z\in Z$ and $y\in Y$.

By definition of $F$, $F(f)=g$.

2. $F$ is injective

Assume $f_1,f_2\in \left(X^Y\right)^Z$ and $F(f_1)=g_1=g_2=F(f_2)$.

$g_1=g_2\implies [\forall (y,z)\in Y\times Z][g_1(y,z)=g_2(y,z)] \implies [\forall (y,z)\in Y\times Z][f_1(z)(y)=f_2(z)(y)] \implies (\forall z\in Z)[(\forall y\in Y)(f_1(z)(y)=f_2(z)(y))] \implies (\forall z\in Z)[f_1(z)=f_2(z)] \implies f_1=f_2$.

To sum up: $F$ is bijective and thus $\left |\left(X^Y\right)^Z\right|=\left|X^{Y\times Z}\right|$.

Comment: Please mention the reason for downvote!

Comment: There's an ongoing debate on meta about whether proof-verification questions should be welcome at all. The downvoter may be someone on the "they shouldn't" side.

Comment: Hi @HenningMakholm! I bet that such people have never experienced the feeling of self-studying **alone**. **alone** exactly means only you and your textbook, no friend and no formal teacher.

Comment: Akira, that might very well be. But if you actually read the arguments for and against these kind of questions, you'll see that your comment is really barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila! I'm sorry for any misunderstanding! After all, that is an issue of Mods and I will follow the rules.

Comment: No, this is not an issue of Mods, this is a topic that affects the entire community, so the community should debate about the future policy as to how to approach these kind of things. The latest discussion in on https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29119/the-problem-with-proof-verification and I invite you to contribute your opinion.

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila! Honestly, I'm really exhausted with learning and thus unable to participate in Meta discussion. I'm very grateful to your time and contribution! BTW, I will wait for your answer in that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks okay, but the definition of your "function" is a bit weird, correct me I am wrong but you are trying to say:

$$F:X^{Y\times Z}\to\left(X^Y\right)^Z\\((F(g))(x))(y)=g(y,x)$$
In other words, $F$ is a function who gets a function $g:Y\times Z\to X$ and return a function $F(g):Z\to X^Y$, this function gets an element from $x\in Z$ and return a function from $F(g)(x):Y\to X$ and this function gets an element from $y\in Y$ and return $((F(g))(x))(y)\in X$.

If this is what you mean then yes, the proof is okay but note that we can define inverse function to prove this easily:$$G:\left(X^Y\right)^Z\to X^{Y\times Z}\\(G(f))(x,y)=(f(y))(x)$$

Comment: Hi @Holo! That's what I intended to communicate. From your notation, $x\in Z, y\in Y$, I guess that you meant $$G:\left(X^Y\right)^Z\to X^{Y\times Z}\\(G(f))(y,x)=(f(x))(y)$$ rather than $$G:\left(X^Y\right)^Z\to X^{Y\times Z}\\(G(f))(x,y)=(f(x))(y)$$

Comment: @Akira yes, this was a typo