# Proving Equipotence of Sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, relations

- Let $A, B$ and $C$ be sets. Show that $\left(A^B \right)^C \thickapprox A^{B \times C}$, that is, these are equipotent.

Let $F: \left(A^B \right)^C \to A^{B \times C}$ be given by $f \mapsto g$, where $f: C \to A^B$ and $g : B \times C \to A$. We need to show that $F$ is bijective.

Assume that there exists $f_1,f_2 \in \left(A^B \right)^C$ and $g \in A^{B \times C}$ such that, $F(f_1) = g = F(f_2)$. How do we proceed?

Comment: You don't explain how to define $g$ in terms of $f$. You will have a hard time showing equality unless you have a clear idea of just what the function $F(f)$ actually *is*...

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, I understand that, but I haven't been able to find an expression for $g$ in terms of $f$.

Comment: Then that's where you want to start. Or try going to the other way...

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g \in \left( A^B\right)^C$ and $g_c = g(c) : B \to A$. $h \in A^{B \times C}$ and $h_c = h(\,\cdot\,, c) : B \to A$ such that $h_c = g_c$. Define $P: A^{B \times C} \to \left(A^B \right)^C$ given by $h \mapsto P(h)$ with $P(h)(c) = h_c$.

**Injectivity**: $\;$Suppose that $P(h) = P(h')$, then $P(h)(c) = P(h')(c)$ $\Rightarrow$ $h_c = h'_c$. Consider now, $h_c(b) = h'_c(b)$ $\Rightarrow$ $h(b,c) = h'(b,c)$. Therefore, $h = h'$.

**Surjectivity**: $\;$Let there be $g \in \left(A^B \right)^C$, such that $g = P(h)$ for some $h \in A^{B \times C}$. We have, $P(h)(c) = h_c = g_c$ $\Rightarrow$ $h_c(b) = g_c(b)$, that is, $h(b,c) = g_c(b)$, which is the same as $\left(P(h)(c) \right)(b) = h(b,c) = g_c(b)$. Therefore, for any $g \in \left(A^B \right)^C$ there is a $h \in A^{B \times C}$ such that $P(h) = g$.

Thus, there is a bijection between the sets, that is, $\left(A^B \right)^C \thickapprox A^{B \times C}$.

---

Ironically, after finishing the argument, I realized that this question is a duplicate of [Let $X,Y,Z$ be nonempty sets. Then $|(X^Y)^Z|=|X^{Y\times Z}|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951487/let-x-y-z-be-nonempty-sets-then-xyz-xy-times-z?rq=1). Sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for the help!